# Cannot understand how this property on a model is being invoked

Tags: python, django, django-models, lambda, django-forms

I am going over a tutorial on extending a user model and it seems to work however I had 2 questions on how a property is being invoked and about a constructor. First this is the code in question

The main model is this

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    likes_cheese = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    puppy_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

User.profile = property(lambda u : UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])--->Statement A
```

Now the form which gets presented to the user is this

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('likes_cheese','puppy_name')
```

and the view that presents this form is as follows this is where my questions are (Over here i am simply interested in presenting the form so I removed the other code out):

```
def user_profile(request):
    display_page = "profile.html"
    csrf_token = csrf(request)
    args={}
    user  = request.user
    profile = user.profile    ---------------------->statement B - Question 1 below
    form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile) ------->statement C - Question 2 below
    args.update(csrf_token)
    args["form"] = form
    return render_to_response(display_page,args)
```

Now here are my two questions

Q1- Why isnt a parameter being passed to the property `profile` of `User` object ?

from what I understand from statement A which is

```
  User.profile = property(lambda u : UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

is that profile is being defined as a property of User and that it has a setter function which is a lambda that takes a parameter. Where is that parameter being passed ? All i see is this (A parameter to the property is not being passed anywhere that I can see)

```
        profile = user.profile   
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)
```

Q2-In the code `form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)` we are passing in an instance as a parameter but my UserProfileForm does not have a constructor ? What is happening here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1**: Because you are using django predefined `User` class you have two options to add new property(to inherit `User` model and say django to use it for just adding new property), or just do it like you did.

When you call `user.profile` you already passing `user` as a parameter, so that `lambda` does `UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)[0]`

**Q2**: Your `UserProfileForm` inherit from `forms.ModelForm` which already has a constructor. And you can pass `instance` argument, so that form would be populated with model data(`UserProfile`).

`django.forms.ModelForm` at the same moment inherit from `django.forms.models.BaseModelForm` and in `__init__` it checks if `instance` keyword argument is provided and populates form as follows, from [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/models/#ModelForm)

```
if instance is None:
    # if we didn't get an instance, instantiate a new one
    self.instance = opts.model()
    object_data = {}
```

Comment: I understand no 2 could you explain 1 , I still dont understand where a value is being passed as a parameter to the property